# I need an api that can upload some data to the web

Tags: c#, html, json

I have an application made with c# which gets something from the user.

I need that piece of information to be submitted to me somehow by that application downloading a string,

for example, I have seen URL shortener APIs that would take a request, then shorten something, and that target URL would appear in my account.

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
    private void example_click(object sender, EventArgs e)`
    {
         WebClient wc1 = new WebClient();
         string datatosend = "example"
         string received = wc1.DownloadString("https://examplesite.com/api?=" + datatosend + "&format=json");
    }
```

Or something along those lines, I used the main format of the shrinkearn API https://shrinkearn.com/, however, I think that there might be a site with their own API that works in this way.

Reference: [DownloadString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Thanks in advance
Martin

Comment: you can always use fake JSON [like this one](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

Comment: Are you asking, in practice, to suggest an existing Online Service that provides an API that *does something* for you?

Comment: You say "upload" in your title but "Download" in code, which is it?  Please add some clarification of the requirement.

Comment: Well, the downloadstring feature is, in my opinion, the easiest way that I can get it to visit a page. The part which would upload would be datatosend, which I would like to be anything

Comment: Yes, I am asking for some kind of service where i can have my own database to access and a link that would function as follows: https://myapp.example.com/?data=datawouldbehere&format=text
then, the words: datawouldbehere would be shown in the database

Comment: What do you mean by 'fake JSON' Also tell me how I can use this, as I do not understand.

Comment: @Jimi I commented above

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  I commented above

Comment: @styx I commented above

Comment: the data itself never appears in the in the URL

Comment: Most of the time, developers create this type of service within their applications.  Asking for a recommendation of such a service would I believe be out of scope for this site which is about the first part, creation of code to do such a thing - and helping you fix issues with your code which creates such a service.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic